# Buttons in an AVD won't work

Tags: android

When Im using the Android AVD a button in my program dont work and i dont know why. The button is a regular button.

Why is this happening and how can i solve it?

Heres the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actiondrama);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActionDramaJa);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {



                  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActiondramaActivity.this,ActionDrama1Activity.class);
             }
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to start the activity :

```
startActivity(intent);
```

After that, feel free to remove `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` since you have used your `intent`.

PS : Next time, be wise when to use `@SuppressWarnings`

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything visible inside the listener. Perhaps you forgot:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you create the Activity Intent but you haven't start the activity, so nothing will happen.

add `startActivity(intent);`

after `Intent intent = new Intent(ActiondramaActivity.this,ActionDrama1Activity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of using `intent` is,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

For your code, you should change it as,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActiondramaActivity.this,ActionDrama1Activity.class);
startActivity(intent); // <-- You are missing this.
```

Also remove `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.